# sed: can't read /ltmain.sh: No such file or directory (cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, autotools

I'm compiling using autotools.  I've used the current setup before, but today it's not working.  I'm on cygwin, and autotools libtool etc, I think I've installed what I need.  I run

```
autoreconf -ivf
cd ./build
../configure
```

and at the end of the configure output I see

```
: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
sed: can't read /ltmain.sh: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'libtoolT': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'libtoolT': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'libtool': No such file or directory
```

Note that the line starting with "sed:" can't read "/ltmain.sh",  no dot in front of the slash.  Any ideas?

Comment: `autoreconf` is for package maintainers.  If you're only trying to build a package with an existing Autotools-based build system then you should skip that, and instead start with running the top-level `configure` script from your intended build directory.  In fact, you need to install the Autotools at all only if you need to *modify* the build system.  That's one of their key design features.

Comment: With that said, it's not at all clear whether running `autoreconf` is related to the problem.  I'm suspicious, because it looks like the build-system internals are failing, but you haven't provided enough information to be sure.  Is there a reason other than simple preference why you don't want to do an in-source build?

Comment: Well, without any further input from you, we simply don't have enough information to answer the question.  Voting to close.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, I apologize.  I've just been swamped writing a final report on a contract.  I was going to ask what other information would be helpful, but I wanted to look into autotools on cygwin a bit more.   Soon after I posted I noticed the same behavior in a different project, but some projects build with no problem.  I.e.  I need to gather more clues.  But I appreciate your quick reply.